# Check certificate thumbprint before doing the actual request. Windows C

Tags: c++, c, windows, certificate, wininet

I have this piece of code:

```
int Request(char* Method, LPCSTR Host, LPCSTR url, LPCSTR header, LPSTR data, bool ssl){
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        HINTERNET internet = InternetOpenA("Firefox", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
        if (internet != NULL)
        {
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
            HINTERNET connect = InternetConnectA(internet, Host, port, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
            if (connect != NULL)
            {
                //Here I want to get the certificate from the server and check the thumbprint. If it's not the want I want I don't do any request
                if(thumbprint != "49023842938429034809234"){
                    InternetCloseHandle(connect);
                    InternetCloseHandle(internet);
                    return error;
                }

                //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
                HINTERNET request = HttpOpenRequestA(connect, m, url, "HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL,
                    dwFlags, NULL);

                if (request != NULL)
                {
                    int datalen = 0;
                    if (data != NULL) datalen = strlen(data);
                    int headerlen = 0;
                    if (header != NULL) headerlen = strlen(header);

                    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
                    HttpSendRequestA(request, header, headerlen, data, datalen);

                    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
                    InternetCloseHandle(request);
                }
            }
            InternetCloseHandle(connect);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(internet);
    }
```

I want to check the thumbprint and if the server does not provide me the expected thumbprint I will close the connection and don't launch the actual request.

I saw this post but the author does a HEAD requests to get it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/04/17/how-to-get-certificate-information-using-wininet-apis.aspx. Can't I get the certificate details just after connect to the server?

Thank you

Comment: You would have to send some sort of request to the server, otherwise no data will come back at all.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I guess that when you connect to the server yo get the certificate details and the certificate itself to create a secure tunnel through you will send the requests. So the certificate details must be already in the client side before doing the request with `HttpOpenRequestA`